# libgdx поворот относительно объекта

Tags: математика, геометрия, libgdx

Имеется объект, который хранит позицию в Vector2; имеется OrthographicCamera, которая перемещается по пространству игрового мира; координаты нажатия (та точка, в которую должен быть направлен объект) получаются с помощью метода unproject() камеры; сам угол получается с помощью метода angle() приблизительно таким кодом:

```
Vector2 v = new Vector2(touchPosition.x, touchPosition.y);
v.angle();
```

Проблема заключается в том, что, когда происходит перемещение камеры, угол расчитывается относительно центра(начала координат) плоскости отсечения и следовательно угол расчитывается неправильно, ниже приведу схематические:

[image: изображение]

Общая рамка представляет собой игровую область, рамка подписанная цифрой 1 область отсечения (с привязанной к ней камерой) с объектом, находящимся по центру этой области (центр камеры). объект изначально направлен своей лицевой стороной помеченной красным цветом на север. Если не перемещать камеру и нажать на точку, помеченную синим цветом, объект поворачивается своей лицевой стороной по направлению к синей точке, то есть на северо-восток, но если переместить камеру в положение 2 и вновь нажать на точку, помеченную зеленым цветом, то следующее направление объекта будет указывать не на северо-восток, а на юго-восток относительно нового центра камеры. Вопрос заключается в том, как организовать поворот объекта относительно центра объекта, а не относительно центра камеры.

Comment: а что мешает сместить начало координат с камеры на объект перед поворотом?

Answer (score 1):

```
x = Gdx.input.getX()-(camera.position.x-Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/2);
y = (Gdx.graphics.getHeight()-Gdx.input.getY())-(camera.position.y-Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/2);
```